# LoggingSession.SaveToFileAsync sometimes creates files ending with .etl.tmp

Tags: c#, logging, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a universal Windows/WindowsPhone 8.1 app where I use LoggingSession to log messages as my app runs.

When an unhandled exception occurs, I log the exception and then I await a call to LoggingSession.SaveToFileAsync to dump the logs to a file. The next time my app is launched I upload the log file and receive it on my end.

The issue I'm seeing is that sometimes my log files end with .etl.tmp (usually files are 50 - 100 Kb in size) and when I try to open them (with tracerpt or Windows Event Viewer) I don't see any logs. Other times I open .etl.tmp files that are usually about 200Kb in size and I see some log entries. And yet other times the log files (usually under 20Kb) correctly end with .etl extension (no .tmp) and all the logged messages are there.

1) Why is that LoggingSession.SaveToFileAsync sometimes generates files with .etl.tmp extension?

2) Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? I need to capture all logs (even the unhandled exception) before saving them to file so that's why I call LoggingSession.SaveToFileAsync in the unhadnled exception event handler of my app. I also need my logging solution to be performant and not to slow down my app too much.

Thanks

---

Here's the stripped down sample code:

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    .
    .
    .

    public static ETWLogger Logger;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Logger = new ETWLogger();

        Suspending += OnSuspending;
        UnhandledException += OnUnhandledExceptionAsync;
    }

    private async void OnUnhandledExceptionAsync(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        await Logger.SaveToFileAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if there are files in the Log folder. If so
        // then upload them and then delete all files in the Log folder.
    }

    .
    .
    .
}

public class ETWLogger
{
    private LoggingSession _session;
    private LoggingChannel _channel;
    private StorageFolder _logFolder;
    .
    .
    .

    public ETWLogger()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        _session = new LoggingSession("DefaultSession");
        _channel = new LoggingChannel("DefaultChannel");
        _session.AddLoggingChannel(_channel);

        _logFolder = StorageHelper.CreateSubFolder(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "LogFiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public async Task SaveToFileAsync()
    {
        if (_session == null) return;

        var fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmssTzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".etl";
        await _session.SaveToFileAsync(_logUploadFolder, fileName);
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: hard for anyone to give you an accurate answer based on the question. Your questions is a valid one however we can't see how you have coded the async code process.. could you show your code in regards to the relevance of your question

Comment: I'm also having this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a pretty good idea what is going on here.  You describe a common technique that Microsoft uses, it prevents file corruption and data loss.  Instead of creating the foo.etl file you asked for, it *first* creates the file with a different name.  Like foo.etl.tmp.  Only when the file is successfully written, or in other words, the async method actually completed, does it rename the file from foo.etl.tmp to foo.etl.

You now have an excellent guarantee that you always get a fully written "good" file.  No corruption.  And if you had a previous file with the same name then it doesn't get replaced with a corrupt half-written file.  No data loss.

> When an unhandled exception occurs, I log the exception and then I await a call

The "unhandled exception" is the problem.  Your log file can only be fully written when the exception is not fatal enough to prevent the async/await plumbing from continuing to work.  Or in other words, you only get the "mild" exception info right now.  The bad ones produce the half-written foo.etl.tmp file, the app keeled over before it could be completed.

You can't afford to use `await` here if you want to know about the "bad" ones.  The SaveToFileAsync() call must complete synchronously.

Comment: Yes I changed the call to a synchronous one and that fixed my issue. I just don't understand why Microsoft uses an awaited call for saving the log file in App unhandled exception handler when it clearly doesn't work and should be synchronous call.

Comment: Hmm, hard to believe Microsoft uses or recommends this.  You are implementing a feature that [is already available](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/13/crash-analysis-in-the-unified-dev-center/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Before I award you the bounty, I'm calling `var logSaveTask = logSession.SaveToFileAsync(logUploadFolder, fileName).AsTask();` then on the next line I call `logSaveTask.Wait();` and I am seeing this issue.  Is that not synchronous enough?  Should I open another question?

Comment: @joe_coolish You're still calling the method asynchronously, you just so happen to not be doing anything between creating the task and waiting for it to complete.  Synchronously calling a task with a return type is done with `MyTask().Result`.  So in your case, you would call something like `var storageFolder = logSession.SaveToFileAsync(logUploadFolder, fileName).Result;`.